# SQL replace a string starting with a specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with text/sentences that may include strings starting with '@'. I need to remove all strings starting with '@' from the texts. For example:

[image]

Is there any function that can do the trick? I have tried the following but this removes only the '@' from the string:

```
SELECT  Column1, 
        LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('@',Column1)+1, LEN(Column1))) AS [Output column]
FROM mytable
WHERE Column1 like '%@%';
```

Comment: SQL Server's forté isn't string manipulation. If you can, I would urge using a language that supports Regex natively. Otherwise you'll likely want to look into CLR functions.

Comment: Where are your strings supposed to end?  Do you actually mean “replace *words* that start with ‘@‘“?  Because that’s much harder.  Unless you already have a specific limited list of words to replace, then it’s more reasonable.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The strings start with '@' and end just before the following string, so there is a space/blank before the next string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select Column1 col, Column1 + ' ' Column1, 1 level from mytable
  union all
  select col,
         left(Column1, charindex('@', Column1) - 1) +
         right(Column1, len(Column1) - charindex(' ', Column1, charindex('@', Column1)) + 1),
         level + 1
  from cte
  where charindex('@', Column1) > 0
)
select distinct rtrim(first_value(Column1) over (partition by col order by level desc)) Column1
from cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5a3bfceef131cb04f9d140b783ab4fc).
Results:

```
> | Column1                               |
> | :------------------------------------ |
> | another text text continues here word |
> | some text here text continue here     |
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and for your help. Sounds a bit advanced for me but will definitely try it.

Answer (score 2):

...for varchar/char only (not for Nvar/Nchar)..it's bad :(

```
declare @t table(id int identity, col1 varchar(100));
insert into @t(col1)
values
('aaaa @bbb cccc ddd @ffff'),
('@aaaa @bbb cccc ddd @ffff @@@@       '),
('@aaaa @bbb cc@@@@@cc  <-- nonleading@ ddd @ffff @@@@       '), 
('123456   '), ('@@@@@@')
;

select *, col1+'{...', 
    cast(
    convert(varbinary(100), 
    replace(
    cast('<!--' + replace(convert(varchar(max), cast(t.col1 as varbinary(100)) , 2), convert(varchar(100), cast(' ' as varbinary(4)), 2), '--><!--') + '-->' as xml).query('data(comment()[substring(., 1, 2) != "40"])').value('.', 'varchar(100)'), 
    ' ',
    convert(varchar(10), cast(' ' as varbinary(2)), 2)), 2)
    as varchar(100)) + '{...'
from @t as t;
```

Comment: Thanks @Iptr, much appreciated. Haven't thought that this would be this complicated (at least for me :)).